# PHP differentating '' and 0

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a teacher gradebook project, and I'm running into an odd quirk of PHP. How do I tell the difference in '' and 0? I am trying to use operators, but I do not have success. Here is some background information:

`$array['grades']['brian']['project']` would be null since there was not a grade entered for this assignment. The student did not score a zero (0) on the assignment, there was just simply not a grade entered. This array value is defined using the HTML `<input value=''>`

Alternatively, `$array['grades']['samuel']['homework']` was scored as a zero (0). There was a grade entered, it is just a failing grade. This array value is defined using the HTML `<input value='0'>`

I need to determine the difference in no grade entered and a grade of zero entered so I can update the SQL table appropriately. I have tried using the operator `if ($array['grades']['samuel']['homework'] === 0)` but this does not trigger anything.

How can I accomplish this task?

**Example array:**

```
Array
(
    [ucid] => 4
    [grades] => Array
        (
            [brian] => Array
                (
                    [project] => 
                    [homework] => 12
                )

            [samuel] => Array
                (
                    [project] => 9
                    [homework] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Use the `===` operator.

Comment: What is the data type of `$array['grades']['samuel']['homework']`, make sure it is an integer, not a string when you use `===` operator

Comment: [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/is_numeric) is_your_friend.

Comment: @catcon The HTML that created Samuel Homework was ```<input value='0'>``` while the HTML that created brian homework was ```<input value=''>```

Comment: Instead of visualizing the data with `print_r()`, use more informative tools such as `var_export()` or better `var_dump()`.

Comment: `is_numeric()` might not be your fiend. You can check the `strlen()`. Or you can explicitly cast the value as `(int)` then use `=== 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track - as long as the values you are testing are actual ints, your === operator should work. However if they are string representations of int, the expression will return false.

```php
<?php

$vals = [
    'zero' => 0,
    'zero_string' => '0',
    'empty_string' => '',
    'null' => null,
    'false' => false
];

// If the type of the var is the same as the type of the test, everything's shiny
assert($vals['zero'] === 0, 'Value should be identical to 0');
assert($vals['empty_string'] === '', 'Value should be identical to ""');
assert($vals['null'] === null, 'Value should be identical to null');
assert($vals['false'] === false, 'Value should be identical to false');

// You can force this with type juggling
assert(intval($vals['zero_string']) === 0, 'Value should be identical to 0');
assert((int) $vals['zero_string'] === 0, 'Value should be identical to 0');

// Uh-oh - string zero and int zero are not the same, so this will fail
assert($vals['zero_string'] === 0, 'Value should be identical to 0');
```

Edit:
Here is a simple way to normalize your inputs so that you can only worry about thype conversion in one place.

```php
<?php

function normalizeGrade($input)
{
    if(is_numeric($input))
    {
        return floatval($input);
    }

    return $input;
}

assert(normalizeGrade('0') == 0, 'String zero should be normalized');
assert(normalizeGrade('90.5') == 90.5, 'String float should be normalized to float');
assert(normalizeGrade('') == '', 'Empty string should be unchanged');
assert(normalizeGrade(null) == null, 'Null should be unchanged');
```

Comment: ```$array['grades']['brian']['project']``` would be set to '', since in the input from the HTML looks like this: ```<input value=''>``` .... would this make any difference?

Comment: OK - I explained how to differentiate zeroes, empty string, and other false-y values in PHP, which was the question. Is this really a "write my code for me" question?

Comment: No sorry I was just not understanding, thank you for your help

Comment: Your best bet is probably to have a function that normalizes all of your values so you can easily test for zero without having to worry about type convesion all over the place. See updated example.

Comment: Please close duplicate questions instead of answering them.  There are literally millions of pages on Stack Overflow.  All basic questions are duplicates in 2021 (and years earlier).  By answering duplicates, you potentially prevent the Roomba from appropriately removing redundant content from this site.